# ExtJS 5.x How to change grid view (viewConfig) after store load?

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have a store in ViewModel like:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.page.PageModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    //...

    stores: {
        Posts: {
            model: //...
        }
    }
});
```

And a grid like:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.page.MainView', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    //...

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        //...

        me.items = [
            {
                xtype: 'grid',
                bind: {
                    store: '{Posts}'
                },
                columns: [ /* ... */ ],
                viewConfig: {
                    getRowClass: function (record) {
                        //...
                    }
                }
            }
        ];

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

How can I change grid view AFTER store load (in my case)?

I tried to use `mon` and `addManagedListener` methods in grid events (`beforerender` and `viewready`) and I tried to use `on` and `addListener` methods to store inside those grid events, but this solution is not working.

Does someone have any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to change? You will have to find where/how the actual setting is set, e.g. you can change the getRowClass function at runtime by overwriting the getRowClass function on the grid view: `grid.getView().getRowClass = function() { ...}`. You may have to rerender the grid (`grid.getView().refresh()`) afterwards for the new function to be applied.

Comment: I want to change `emptyText` parameter in `viewConfig` of `grid`. But I need to do this only after loading store. And your solution is not resolving issue, because from any store events I don't have access to his upper component (`grid` in my case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using override for Ext.view.AbstractView, just to clear emptyEl and viewEl before store load event

```
store.on('beforeload', function() {
    me.clearEmptyEl();
    me.clearViewEl();
});
```

Here is my complete override

```
Ext.define('Ext.overrides.view.AbstractView', {
    override: 'Ext.view.AbstractView',

    onBindStore: function(store, initial, propName) {
        var me = this;

        me.setMaskBind(store);
        // After the oldStore (.store) has been unbound/bound,
        // do the same for the old data source (.dataSource).
        if (!initial && propName === 'store') {
            // Block any refresh, since this means we're binding the store, which will kick off
            // a refresh.
            me.preventRefresh = true;
            // Ensure we have the this.store reference set correctly.
            me.store = store;
            me.bindStore(store, false, 'dataSource');
            me.preventRefresh = false;
        }
        store.on('beforeload', function() {
            me.clearEmptyEl();
            me.clearViewEl();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Many thanks, @A.Pokidin!!! It is not exactly what I need, but I've tried your solution and I liked it! The overrides of ExtJS components are so difficult for me today, so you very helped me with my issue! Have a nice day))

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJS 6, a function `setEmptyText` is available on the grid that will do this for you:

```
initComponent: function () {
    var me = this;
    //...

    me.callParent(arguments);
    me.getStore().on('load', function() {
        me.setEmptyText(...);
    })
}
```

In ExtJS 5, you have to do on your own:

```
    me.getStore().on('load', function() {
       var emptyText = 'Test empty text';
       me.getView().emptyText = '<div class="' + me.emptyCls + '">' + emptyText + '</div>';
       me.getView().refresh();
    })
```

[Relevant fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/26i8), will load its store 3 seconds after rendering.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Alexander! Your example works very well and I will save it for future features. In my case I can't use this solution, because `me` is not grid - it is his parent - panel, and for using this I need to refactor all code... =(

Comment: No, you don't have to. You can use `var grid = me.down('grid')` and after that, exchange all instances of "me" with "grid".

Comment: I tried to use it earlier (before I wrote my question), but event listener (like in your fiddle example) not calling in my case, in my project. I think it is because some actions prevent his. But I don't know what exactly and I can't find it.

Comment: The `load` event listener does not call if no records are transmitted; could that be the issue?

Comment: I tried when records exist in store and when don't. Unfortunately, it is not working and I suppose it is not issue. I know - it is strange...  О_о